# I got an error when I try to run my Twilio-make a call project

Tags: python, makefile, twilio, call

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\call and text\main.py", line 8, in
>
> account_sid = os.environ['my account sid']   File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\os.py",
> line 679, in __getitem__
> raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'my auth_token '

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing the `my auth_token` in the envrion.

Check your Client configurations and make sure you are setting values for both `my auth_token` and `my_account_sid` in the environ. These are needed.

Comment: Thank you for replaying me. I tried it but still i'm getting error

Comment: Without sharing the values of the SID and Token, can you tell me how you are setting them in the environment? As you are on a Windows machine you will need to set those 2 in environmental variables or use a .env file and refer it from there.